# C#, WPF Bindingarray to ListBox won't Work

Tags: c#, data-binding, listbox

I can't get the binding of an array to a ListBox to work.

I have looked on the web and tried many ways none of which were successful. It seems that the data is shown in the ItemsSource but not shown in the listbox.

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : ThemedWindow
{
    public string selectedItem { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyFiles { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(TextEdit.Text);
        MyFiles = new ObservableCollection<string>(filePaths);
        selectedItem = MyFiles[0];
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(filePath);
            string file = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox"
            BorderThickness="2"
            Height="352"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyFiles}"
            Margin="92,0,95.6,10"
            SelectedItem="{Binding selectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionMode="Single" 
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="606"
            />
```

No error messages just does not show the output in the ListBox

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I am an amature and did not understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the binding is done before you create it the instance.

Try this at the declaration:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyFiles { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

And replace:

```
MyFiles = new ObservableCollection<string>(filePaths);
```

With:

```
foreach(var file in filePaths)
    MyFiles.Add(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the collection after the data context is set, You must make your property `MyFiles` notifiable with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Or, you create it only once in the contructor and then, you just Add or Remove items. Setting the porperty with a new instance of a collection breaks the binding.

Comment: Thanks. Did not understand as I am a beginner.